# avoid loading all choices in ModelChoiceField for loading values throug ajax

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a form with ModelChoice field. The field is filtered by ajax request.

```
self.fields['center'].queryset = TrainingCenter.objects.all()
```

this is works fine. but I am loading the values using ajax based on another field.

if I use a empty queryset to load the form without choices, I am getting "Invalid Choice" error on submit.

- how to avoid loading all the choices without making error on submission

Answer (score 1):

You can write an `EmptySelect` widget class that ignores the choices that are passed to it, like this:

```py
from django import forms


class EmptySelect(forms.Select):
    def _get_choices(self):
        return ()
    
    def _set_choices(self, value):
        pass
    
    choices = property(_get_choices, _set_choices)
```

Then, define your field with the queryset that you want to validate against and configure `EmptySelect` as your widget.

```py
 center = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=TrainingCenter.objects.all(),
    widget=EmptySelect
)
```

You can inherit from other choice widgets too, or even turn `EmptySelect` into a mixin that you can use with any choice widget.